# c - GTK3.0 GUI freezes when using "g_spawn_async_with_pipes()"

Tags: c, user-interface, asynchronous, gtk, freeze

I've written a very simple front end for `ffmpeg` (converting stuff: video -> mp3) in GTK3.0/C for linux. For spawning ffmpeg I use `g_spawn_async_with_pipes()`. I thought this was the right way to execute stuff like that without having the GUI freeze up - but it does though. So - how can I prevent it from freezing - so I can f.e. display a spinner?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide more information, like what environment you're using and a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add something like"

```
    while (gtk_events_pending ()) {
      gtk_main_iteration_do (FALSE);
}
```

That is, to let GTK process the pending events (like drawing the UI).
I suppose you are processing the output of ffmpeg with g_io_add_watch
or similar.